# $\ell_q$ is not finitely representable in $\ell_p$ if $2<q<p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

This seems to be a well known result in Banach space theory. It is referenced, for example, in Pietsch's book "History of Banach spaces and Linear Operator".

Where can I find a proof?

Who was the first to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It follows easily from Theorem 6.4.19 and Theorem 11.1.8 in Topics In Banach Space Theory by Albiac/Kalton.  I have no idea who first proved it, sorry.